# Small ripple in 555 timer output when connected with a 2nd 555 timer chip

Tags: 555, ripple

I have two 555 timer chips.  The 1st is used to create a transition every .1 seconds while the 2nd is used in a monostable configuration to debounce a button. When using my DLA to look at the output of the debouncing 555 timer, I am seeing small spikes in the output that correspond exactly with the frequency of the output of the other oscillating 555 timer.  I have attached my schematic showing my interconnections. Note the schematic shows connections to a terminal block. However, in my breadboarded version I have a 100K Ohm resistor tied to positions 7 and 8 of the block and a button tied to 5 and 6.

It is also the case that the LED's along with current limiting resistors or NOT in my current circuit when I am doing this recording.

I have also attached a screen shot of the trace from my DLA.

[image: Schematic]

[image: DLA Trace]

The 555 timer I am using is the SA555 chip.

Any thoughts on how to prevent this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: With Decoupling capacitors of .1uF and .01uF on the power rail of the 2nd 555 timer]

Comment: This is just a canned comment to let you know that what you're trying to build from discrete analog components (possibly incorporating Opamps and/or NE555) is a digital control problem and thus can easily and with lower parts count be solved with a microcontroller with really minimal firmware to write.

Comment: I don't see any decoupling caps on the supply rails of the ICs, you might start there if they really don't exist.

Comment: Thanks @JohnD I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, am aware of that.  I am working on an educational project that specifically uses the 555 timer chip as part of the experience. :-)

Comment: @KevinMcQuown that's an excellent reason :)

Comment: @JohnD Added a .1uF and .01uF capacitor on the power input to the 2nd 555 timer chip where I was seeing the issue. Uploaded a new DLA trace.  Much, much better. Should I assume this is about as good as it gets?

Comment: Make sure your power leads are as short as possible and star-connected to a common point, not daisy-chained.

Comment: @KevinMcQuown With an optimal PCB layout you might get a little better, but it doesn't look too bad to me.

Comment: A 555 shorts out the supply every time it switches. Some glitches will always be there. This is a good reason to never use one in your design.

Answer (score 3):

You have no decoupling on your components. IC's have recommended decoupling capacitors on VCC/ power inputs for that very reason - to decouple the IC from extraneous noise in your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Needed decoupling capacitors.  Once I added a .1uF and .01uF capacitor to the vcc input of the 2nd 555 timer, the high state smoothed out considerably.